# Axios Access-Control-Allow-Origin error

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, api, reactjs, axios

El problema es que al consultar por get a la url de mi api, que esta ya publicada en heroku axios me devuelve el siguiente error: 
"falta la cabecera CORS 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' ", lo cual tiene sentido porque la poticion http se hace a otro dominio. El problema es que mi api si devuelve esa cabecera, lo tengo configurado mediante middleware en laravel con el siguiente codigo:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $response = $next($request);

    $response->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

    return $response;
}
```

Cuando pruebo la api con Postman y verifico los headers este si aparece. No entiendo por qué razón axios no lo reconoce.

La diferencia entre mi pregunta y la existente es que en mi caso el header si existe en el response, cuando lo pruebo desde postman veo que su valor es '*', al acceder a la api desde una aplicacion react funciona perfectamente.

Al trabajar en un proyecto laravel se puede utilizar blade como motor de platillas u otros frameworks como react o vue. En mi caso configure laravel para utilizar react y es solo ahi donde obtengo el error. No se si es problema de compatibilidad entre los frameworks, o si varia la version de react y eso da conflicto o algo por el estilo